# DataTable doesn't work (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have made a simple table to show dataTable something like this in [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html). The problem is I have tried to do in a similar way like it does.

First of all, I have put the coding below:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I don't forget to call function something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

And also I have call external sources as suggested like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.data"></script>
```

The problem is it doesnt work as shown as [here.](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html)Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y913yh4u/). Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Read this : http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/

Comment: you didn't include main datatable js file and  it's `dataTable` not `DataTable()` check this http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/y913yh4u/1/

Comment: @Learner Hello, thanks for the hints, anyway, can you check that jsfiddle for pagination? It doesn't work at all. like previous and next. It should be show page numbers.

Comment: hi @Anthosiast next previous disabled because table has just 9 rows  it will enabled when record increased check here http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/y913yh4u/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this link [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/y913yh4u/2/) you must include the js correctly

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh. That's working now. By the way, pagination for dataTable doesn't work. Wondering what's the problem. Here is http://prntscr.com/5qnfvy.

Comment: u want pagination with numbers ?

Comment: yeah I want pagination with numbers.

Comment: It's still the same, not working thou.. I have 18 rows. Should be 2 page numbers.

Comment: `$('#myTable').dataTable( { "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" } );`  Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/y913yh4u/6/

Answer (score 4):

I spent hours working this out, turns out I was missing tags needed for the Search to work:

```
<thead></thead>
```

and the

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove // from the beginning of links. And include **https://** before these links. i also faced this issue. But now its working.

Answer (score 0):

To make the table working what you can do is,

```
$(window).load(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        $('table').DataTable();
    }, 1100);
})
```

Comment: @kyun, thnx ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Add `$.noConflict();` to your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});

</script>
```